# get all columns of type Date/timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle

in oracle, I want to get all columns of type DATE/TIMESTAMP(6) and i did the following. But I get the error '00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"'

My query:

```
Select column_name ,DATA_TYPE from user_tab_columns 
Where Table_name = 'ACCOUNT' Where DATA_TYPE IN('DATE','TIMESTAMP(6)');
```

I searched stackoverflow for related issue, but can't find. do assist. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used WHERE clause twice, use AND instead

Use like this

```
SELECT column_name, DATA_TYPE from user_tab_columns WHERE table_name = 'ACCOUNT' AND DATA_TYPE IN('DATE','TIMESTAMP(6)');
```

Answer (score 0):

Terms in a `WHERE` clause should be separated by `AND`, and also `WHERE` only appears once:

```
select column_name,
       DATA_TYPE
from user_tab_columns
where table_name = 'ACCOUNT' and
      DATA_TYPE IN('DATE','TIMESTAMP(6)');
```